# Validate MapRoute in MVC if URL contains at least one minus sign

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm working with MVC and I want to add a constraint to a route and validate only if URL seems like that:

> mysite/example-of-url-with-minus-sign

So I need something like that :

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "Categories", 
                url: "{category}", 
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Category" }, 
                constraints: new { category = @"[-]+" } 
       );
```

Comment: please provide some sample and expected result. also it's better to show your effort first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your constraint like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "DefaultWithMinus",
    url: "{cat}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "WithMinus", cat = UrlParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { cat = @"\w*-+\w*" }
);
```

The action in HomeController

```
public ActionResult WithMinus(string cat)
{
    return Content($"With Minus: {cat}");
}
```

Results:

> http://localhost:49651/- => With Minus: -
>
> http://localhost:49651/asdfds- => With Minus: asdfds-
>
> http://localhost:49651/asdfds-sdfg => With Minus: asdfds-sdfg
>
> http://localhost:49651/-sdfg => With Minus: -sdfg

Obs.: This route only handle one level, so if you the something like **www.site.com/fasdf-sadfsd/secondlevel** it will fail.

Obs².: If you need something more specific, you should create youe custom route constraint: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-custom-route-constraint-cs

Comment: Hi Alberto,
I'm working with MVC and I want to add a constraint to a route and validate only if URL seems like that : mysite/example-of-url-with-minus-sign So I need something like that : 

`routes.MapRoute( name: "Categories", url: "{category}", defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Category" }, constraints: new { category = @"[-]+" } );`

Comment: @LaurentKnafo I changed my answer, look now

Comment: @LaurentKnafo can you mark my answer as correct one?

Comment: Yes but I can't add points because I have to earn first 15 points because I'm new on the site.

Comment: @LaurentKnafo Thanks, there is no problem I knew that you could not app points. Making it the correct answer is enough. I am happy that it solved your problem.